# URN for MIME Type

Tags: mime, mime-types, urn

Does an official URN for the MIME type exist?

Mozilla Firefox and other applications use notations like "`urn:mimetype:text/plain`" or "`urn:mimetype:handler:text/plain`".
There are two problems with this approach:

1. No "`mimetype`" namespace exists according to the IANA's official registry (http://www.iana.org/assignments/urn-namespaces/). Thus, only "`urn:x-mimetype`" would be a valid namespace (according to RFC 3406 section 4.1).
2. The slash "`/`" may not be used in URNs according to RFC 2141 section 2.2. But it could be encoded to "`%2F`".

All that considered, is there another way to represent the MIME type "`text/plain`" as an URN than "`urn:x-mimetype:text%2Fplain`"?

[UPDATE: Thinking about it, an URI would be ok too. But I can't find no URI for MIME type neither.]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, I read the presence of `/` as a SHOULD NOT by RFC 2141, rather than a MUST NOT.

For this approach I would just use the URI of the assignment, e.g. <http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/zip>. The only caveat is that not all of them dereference. If you can live with that though, you should be OK.

Comment: @user227745, that is a URL, not a URN

Comment: @smartcaveman: OP said that "an URI would be ok too", which includes URLs.